# Android: Add Digital Signature in xml Document Using DigitalSigner

Tags: java, android, xml, digital-signature

I am trying to use below Class to append digital signature in xml request while posting the xml on http server. But As Android doesn't allow me to use the javax.xml.crypto.dsig. package I am  unable  to use it.
**PN DigitalSigner is the 3rd party Class that they want us to use to sign the xml So my question is Is there any other way to sign the Xml Request without using javax.xml.crypto.dsig. if yes then how..?**

thanks in advance

Here is the Class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.CanonicalizationMethod;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.DigestMethod;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.Reference;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.SignatureMethod;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.SignedInfo;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.Transform;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignature;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureFactory;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.dom.DOMSignContext;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.keyinfo.KeyInfo;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.keyinfo.KeyInfoFactory;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.keyinfo.X509Data;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.spec.C14NMethodParameterSpec;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.spec.TransformParameterSpec;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;


public class DigitalSigner {

    private static final String MEC_TYPE = "DOM";
    private static final String WHOLE_DOC_URI = "";
    private static final String KEY_STORE_TYPE = "PKCS12";

    private KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry keyEntry;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param keyStoreFile - Location of .p12 file
     * @param keyStorePassword - Password of .p12 file
     * @param alias - Alias of the certificate in .p12 file
     */
    public DigitalSigner(InputStream keyStoreFile, char[] keyStorePassword, String alias) {
        this.keyEntry = getKeyFromKeyStore(keyStoreFile, keyStorePassword, alias);


        if (keyEntry == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Key could not be read for digital signature. Please check value of signature "
                    + "alias and signature password, ");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to digitally sign an XML document.
     * @param xmlDocument - Input XML Document.
     * @return Signed XML document
     */
    public String signXML(String xmlDocument, boolean includeKeyInfo) {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        try {
            // Parse the input XML
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
            Document inputDocument = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlDocument)));

            // Sign the input XML's DOM document
            Document signedDocument = sign(inputDocument, includeKeyInfo);

            // Convert the signedDocument to XML String
            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer trans = tf.newTransformer();
            trans.transform(new DOMSource(signedDocument), new StreamResult(stringWriter));

            return stringWriter.getBuffer().toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Error while digitally signing the XML document", e);
        }
    }

    private Document sign(Document xmlDoc, boolean includeKeyInfo) throws Exception {

        if (System.getenv("SKIP_DIGITAL_SIGNATURE") != null) {
            return xmlDoc;
        }

        // Creating the XMLSignature factory.
        XMLSignatureFactory fac = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance(MEC_TYPE);
        // Creating the reference object, reading the whole document for
        // signing.
        Reference ref = fac.newReference(WHOLE_DOC_URI, fac.newDigestMethod(DigestMethod.SHA1, null),
                Collections.singletonList(fac.newTransform(Transform.ENVELOPED, (TransformParameterSpec) null)), null,
                null);

        // Create the SignedInfo.
        SignedInfo sInfo = fac.newSignedInfo(
                fac.newCanonicalizationMethod(CanonicalizationMethod.INCLUSIVE, (C14NMethodParameterSpec) null),
                fac.newSignatureMethod(SignatureMethod.RSA_SHA1, null), Collections.singletonList(ref));

        if (keyEntry == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Key could not be read for digital signature.");
        }

        X509Certificate x509Cert = (X509Certificate) keyEntry.getCertificate();

        KeyInfo kInfo = getKeyInfo(x509Cert, fac);
        DOMSignContext dsc = new DOMSignContext(this.keyEntry.getPrivateKey(), xmlDoc.getDocumentElement());
        XMLSignature signature = fac.newXMLSignature(sInfo, includeKeyInfo ? kInfo : null);
        signature.sign(dsc);

        Node node = dsc.getParent();
        return node.getOwnerDocument();

    }


    private KeyInfo getKeyInfo(X509Certificate cert, XMLSignatureFactory fac) {
        // Create the KeyInfo containing the X509Data.
        KeyInfoFactory kif = fac.getKeyInfoFactory();
        List x509Content = new ArrayList();
        x509Content.add(cert.getSubjectX500Principal().getName());
        x509Content.add(cert);
        X509Data xd = kif.newX509Data(x509Content);
        return kif.newKeyInfo(Collections.singletonList(xd));
    }

    private KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry getKeyFromKeyStore(InputStream keyStoreFile, char[] keyStorePassword, String alias) {
        // Load the KeyStore and get the signing key and certificate.
        InputStream keyFileStream = null;
        try {
            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KEY_STORE_TYPE);
            keyFileStream = keyStoreFile;
            ks.load(keyFileStream, keyStorePassword);

            KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry entry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) ks.getEntry(alias,
                    new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(keyStorePassword));
            return entry;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (keyFileStream != null) {
                try {
                    keyFileStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [Apache Santuario](http://santuario.apache.org/):

> Apache XML Security for Java: This library includes the standard JSR-105 (Java XML Digital Signature) API,  a mature DOM-based implementation of both XML Signature and XML Encryption, as well as a more recent StAX-based (streaming) XML Signature and XML Encryption implementation.

So it should be compatible with the Java SE implementation of digital signature, both have been derived from JSR-105. The standalone development implementation has been removed from the Oracle site, unfortunately.

Comment: Note: cannot vouch for the security of above platform, I don't use it myself (I just knew it existed).

Comment: I tried doing this but some how I am getting digital verification error from respective 3rd party vendors and also it needs some more jar to include.

Comment: Well, you cannot have the functionality without the functionality. I don't think you can do this without a lib, except for programming it yourself or just integrating the correct Java classes from either one of them. As for the verification error, you may need to create a trust store or add certificates to the existing one.